# How to change css for specified element?

Tags: css

```
<div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid ekstraclass">
<div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid ekstraclassleft">
<div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid ekstraclassright">
    </div></div></div>
```

How to customize these divs to be `ekstraclassleft {width:70%;}` and `ekstraclassright {width:30%;}`? I want them to float one by another? 
How my style.css file should look like?
 I used `.ekstraclassleft` and `ekstraclassright` as selectors. How make `ekstraclassleft` to be on left and `ekstraclassright` on right. What css rules are for that?

Answer (score 1):

The CSS rule for **float left** is

```
float: left
```

And **float right** follows the same format.

So, you would have

```
.ekstraclassleft {
    float: left
}
```

and then follow the same format for .ekstraclassright.

Comment: is that possible that my other classes blocks my css rules?

Comment: Very possible, considering the nature of CSS.  The other possibility is that you haven't set up your CSS correctly for the elements you wish to float.  Could you post your full CSS?  Thank you.